# I copied a blueprint, but the copies disappeared?

Tags: eve-online

I created a copying job for my Hobgoblin I blueprint, using one of my Advanced Mobile Laboratories (with the copying speed bonus) - this is set to take the blueprint from the Corporate Hangar "Ammunition and Charges", where the original blueprint lives, and then deliver the output to the same hangar;

[image]

Once the job has finished, I deliver it to the destination hangar;

[image]

However, inside that hangar, only the original blueprint arrives;

[image]

Where did the blueprint copies I just made go?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some, quite unintuitive, reason - these seem to be stored over at the POS, rather than being delivered to station where the process was started like the original blueprint. To access them you will need the corporation rights to access the storage of the mobile lab you used to copy the blueprint and then they will be in the destination hangar you originally selected;

[image]

Comment: That is by design. The reason is simply that the data of blueprint can be wired via radio to the lab. But the copies are physical devices that the lab puts out and therefore cannot be "beamed" to the station. Now one could argue that the lab could transmit the data to the station where it is put into the devices that hold it, but alas, I blame drunken Gallentean Scientists.

Comment: That's a pretty decent in world explanation!

Comment: Well it is the official one, hehe. Apart from the drunken scientists of course ;).